# How to fetch rss feeds using simple_html_dom.php

Tags: dom, rss, simple-html-dom

How  can i fetch rss feed (title,link and description tags together) using simple_html_dom.php. I have actually fetched title,link and descritpion separately using simple_html_dom.php but i cant fetch it together. I have fetched tags separately using this code.

```
    foreach($html->find('title') as $element) 
           echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

but actually i want to do like this (This code is not working,synthax error)

```
 foreach(($html->find('title') as $element_1)&&$html->find('link') as $element_2)&&$html->find('description') as $element_3)) 
{
           echo $element_1->plaintext . '<br>';
echo $element_2->plaintext . '<br>';
echo $element_3->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

Do you have any idea about this.

Advance thanks for the help